Rechargeable battery heats up when above insulaton got breached, why?

A nephew inserted a single Eneloop Pro 2550 mAh rechargeable battery into a toy double battery compartment and the spring scratched the top of the battery (see above), then the battery heated up with smoke and smell. Why did it happen? is it because the battery top hidden by insulation is also connected to the battery bottom? Shouldn't battery top (positive) be isolated (even under insulation) from battery bottom (negative) to avoid such accident?

The bottom part is one continuous can, image from the manufacturer's website:

I don't agree that it "should be isolated" under the insulation, however the insulation should be reasonably robust.
You might want to investigate whether the Eneloop Pro batteries you have are actually real or not, there have been poor quality fakes being sold on dodgy sites such as eBay for the past 5 or 10 years, so I would not be surprised to find them in flea markets etc.
One way to distinguish might be the weight.

The whole cylinder is the negative bottom terminal.
When it was inserted into a toy incorrectly the spring connected the positive terminal with negative causing a short circuit, a large current went through and heated up the shorting metal which melted.
Part of the problem is the battery compartments of the toys, with are sometimes rather poor, snug fit or sharp edges peeling away battery insulation when repeatedly inserting and removing the same set of batteries, and terminals that may short circuit if batteries are inserted poorly at an angle or with incorrect polarity as the holder negative terminal is just a loose spring able to easily short the battery terminals.
This is exactly the reason why many toys have manuals in which they mention rechargeable cells should not be used in toys or handled by children. What happened to you is the safety reason why, the batteries are dangerous if something happens. Years ago in a local newspaper there was a mention about an incident with rechargeable batteries being used in a well-known brand baby monitor right next to a sleeping baby - also against the manual instructions, but it was bought second-hand so the parents did not have the manual and used rechargeables against the instructions. Something happened, and Fortunately they noticed the smoking baby monitor in time before anything happened and learnt the hard way about rechargeables being unsuitable near children.

Is it also true for batteries that are not rechargeable?

@Jtl They are safer. They are still just as easily short-circuited, but rechargeable AA cells can push out 5x to 20x more current than a non-rechargeable. This is why generally alkaline batteries don't melt wires or heat them up red hot, but rechargeables can melt wires or worse, heat them up red hot without the metal melting to act as a fuse.
